# MoPub returns "Ad server returned no inventory"

Tags: ads, mopub

I'm trying to display the native ad from mopub. The test ad was displayed ok. But once it turned to show the real native ads, it fails with the following error "Ad server returned no inventory". This error is not explained, or i can't find any docs regarding this error.
I'm using the latest iOS SDK.

Please help with this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution?